Problem with Heroku deployment | H10 error code
I try to deploy my FastAPI application via Heroku but I had an error message when I'm trying to test my application with postman
2024-07-27T15:39:14.021635+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2024-07-27T15:39:14.888419+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/v1/users" host=envy-app-database-4139c41d71a7.herokuapp.com request_id=8b66a3a8-2879-46c5-90db-2ab6d549c07c fwd="92.239.210.215" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

On my machine this application works perfectly.
I configured my application using different guides but it did not help me, what can I do yet?
requirements.txt


psycopg2==2.9.9
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
aiofiles==23.2.1
aiogram==3.10.0
aiohttp==3.9.5
aiosignal==1.3.1
annotated-types==0.7.0
anyio==4.4.0
attrs==23.2.0
certifi==2024.7.4
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
dnspython==2.6.1
email_validator==2.2.0
fastapi==0.111.1
fastapi-cli==0.0.4
fastapi-utils==0.7.0
frozenlist==1.4.1
greenlet==3.0.3
gunicorn==22.0.0
h11==0.14.0
httpcore==1.0.5
httptools==0.6.1
httpx==0.27.0
idna==3.7
Jinja2==3.1.4
magic-filter==1.0.12
markdown-it-py==3.0.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
mdurl==0.1.2
multidict==6.0.5
mypy-extensions==1.0.0
packaging==24.1
psutil==5.9.8
pydantic==2.8.2
pydantic-settings==2.3.4
pydantic_core==2.20.1
Pygments==2.18.0
python-dotenv==1.0.1
python-multipart==0.0.9
PyYAML==6.0.1
rich==13.7.1
shellingham==1.5.4
sniffio==1.3.1
SQLAlchemy==2.0.31
starlette==0.37.2
typer==0.12.3
typing-inspect==0.9.0
typing_extensions==4.12.2
uvicorn==0.30.3
watchfiles==0.22.0
websockets==12.0
yarl==1.9.4


That's my Procfile
web: uvicorn main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT:-5000}
And finally my main.py file
import sys
import os

from controllers import user_controller, task_controller
from database import engine

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from controllers.user_controller import *
from models import user_model

user_model.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


app.include_router(user_controller.router, tags=['Users'], prefix='/api/v1/users')
app.include_router(task_controller.router, tags=['Tasks'], prefix='/api/v1/tasks')

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}



